# Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js' docker in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: javascript, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm learning Docker as a beginner I have to faced this error When I was run this command on my ubuntu 22.04 terminal. Command bellow:

`docker run hello-docker`

But unfortunately my terminal says:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1056
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1053:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:898:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:84:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v19.4.0
```

I need to run my simple js code on docker. Is is file or folder permission issues?

Here is file structure:

```
project dir: /var/www/hello-docker
project file: app.js, Dockerfile
```

```
app.js:
console.log('Hello Docker')
```

```
Dockerfile:
FROM node:alpine
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD node app.js
```

### Build docker file:

```
sudo docker build -t hello-docker
```

### Run docker image:

```
sudo docker run hello-docker
```

Finally I have got error, Previously I have attached.

Thanks

Comment: Double check: if you `docker run --rm hello-docker ls`, is the script file there?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. If you're getting errors, please add them to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are missed the `npm install` command on dockerfile

Dcokerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
CMD node app.js
```

Comment: There's no `package.json` involved. Also, you missed a `RUN`.

Comment: Thanks, @robertklep  I have updated with RUN

Comment: Still no idea why running `npm install` would fix the issue, though.